# Is there a way to gauge the graphical performance of an Android device at runtime?

Tags: android, animation

More specifically, is there a way to check the frame rate of an animation?

I am asking this because I would like to let the user know if his device is too slow for an app for which the smoothness of animation is critical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always used the classical approach of yanking the time at the beginning of the render process and the end and then find the differences. Is that not enough for you case?

Frame rate is going to be highly dependent on what your are rendering and your code will presumably be calling the render methods so a timer seems the most direct and correct approach.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Andrew.  I did not realize that the onDraw() of the custom view is called repeatedly by the animation until I read your answer.  In this case, of course, the effective frame rate can be measured easily. It is essentially the frequency of calling onDraw().